# How to define Dim using dynamic variables as arguments in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code:

```
Function test(data As Range)

Const nobs As Integer = data.Columns.Count

'Const nobs As Integer = 2  <- this one works, but not dynamic

Dim AMatrix(1 To nobs, 1 To nobs) As Variant

End Function
```

`Dim` needs a constant value in it's argument. How can I use my dynamically  changing *nobs* variable instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [ReDim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) and your `Nobs` must be a variable not a constant.

```
Dim Nobs As Long
Nobs = Data.Columns.Count

ReDim AMatrix(1 To Nobs, 1 To Nobs) As Variant
```

Note that `Columns.Count` returns a `Long` not an `Integer`.

Also note that your `Function` should either return a value or you should switch it to a procudure `Sub`.